# Adding unused formal parameters to C++ method results in different behavior

Tags: c++

When I add some extra formal parameters `double tmin=0.0, double tmax=0.0` to the constructor of the `Ray` in the code below, I always obtain a wrong image with a white top border. These formal parameters currently contribute in no way (i.e. are unused) to the code. So how is it possible to obtain a different image?

**System specifications**:

- OS: Windows 8.1
- Compiler: MSVC 2015

**[Code](http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/):**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <random>
std::default_random_engine generator(606418532);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0, 1.0);
double erand48(unsigned short *x) {
    return distribution(generator);
}
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

struct Vector3 {
    double x, y, z;
    Vector3(double x_ = 0, double y_ = 0, double z_ = 0) { x = x_; y = y_; z = z_; }
    Vector3 operator+(const Vector3 &b) const { return Vector3(x + b.x, y + b.y, z + b.z); }
    Vector3 operator-(const Vector3 &b) const { return Vector3(x - b.x, y - b.y, z - b.z); }
    Vector3 operator*(double b) const { return Vector3(x*b, y*b, z*b); }
    Vector3 mult(const Vector3 &b) const { return Vector3(x*b.x, y*b.y, z*b.z); }
    Vector3& norm() { return *this = *this * (1 / sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)); }
    double Dot(const Vector3 &b) const { return x*b.x + y*b.y + z*b.z; } // cross:
    Vector3 operator%(Vector3&b) { return Vector3(y*b.z - z*b.y, z*b.x - x*b.z, x*b.y - y*b.x); }
};

//struct Ray { Vector3 o, d; Ray(const Vector3 &o_, const Vector3 &d_, double tmin=0.0, double tmax=0.0) : o(o_), d(d_) {} };
struct Ray { Vector3 o, d; Ray(const Vector3 &o_, const Vector3 &d_) : o(o_), d(d_) {} };

enum Reflection_t { DIFFUSE, SPECULAR, REFRACTIVE };
struct Sphere {
    double rad;       // radius
    Vector3 p, e, f;      // position, emission, color
    Reflection_t reflection_t;      // reflection type (DIFFuse, SPECular, REFRactive)
    Sphere(double rad_, Vector3 p_, Vector3 e_, Vector3 f_, Reflection_t reflection_t) :
        rad(rad_), p(p_), e(e_), f(f_), reflection_t(reflection_t) {}
    double intersect(const Ray &r) const {
        Vector3 op = p - r.o;
        double t, eps = 1e-4, b = op.Dot(r.d), det = b*b - op.Dot(op) + rad*rad;
        if (det<0) return 0; else det = sqrt(det);
        return (t = b - det)>eps ? t : ((t = b + det)>eps ? t : 0);
    }
};

Sphere spheres[] = {
    Sphere(1e5, Vector3(1e5 + 1,40.8,81.6), Vector3(),Vector3(.75,.25,.25),DIFFUSE),//Left
    Sphere(1e5, Vector3(-1e5 + 99,40.8,81.6),Vector3(),Vector3(.25,.25,.75),DIFFUSE),//Rght
    Sphere(1e5, Vector3(50,40.8, 1e5),     Vector3(),Vector3(.75,.75,.75),DIFFUSE),//Back
    Sphere(1e5, Vector3(50,40.8,-1e5 + 170), Vector3(),Vector3(),           DIFFUSE),//Frnt
    Sphere(1e5, Vector3(50, 1e5, 81.6),    Vector3(),Vector3(.75,.75,.75),DIFFUSE),//Botm
    Sphere(1e5, Vector3(50,-1e5 + 81.6,81.6),Vector3(),Vector3(.75,.75,.75),DIFFUSE),//Top
    Sphere(16.5,Vector3(27,16.5,47),       Vector3(),Vector3(1,1,1)*.999, SPECULAR),//Mirr
    Sphere(16.5,Vector3(73,16.5,78),       Vector3(),Vector3(1,1,1)*.999, REFRACTIVE),//Glas
    Sphere(600, Vector3(50,681.6 - .27,81.6),Vector3(12,12,12),  Vector3(), DIFFUSE) //Lite
};
inline double clamp(double x) { return x<0 ? 0 : x>1 ? 1 : x; }
inline int toInt(double x) { return int(pow(clamp(x), 1 / 2.2) * 255 + .5); }
inline bool intersect(const Ray &r, double &t, int &id) {
    double n = sizeof(spheres) / sizeof(Sphere), d, inf = t = 1e20;
    for (int i = int(n); i--;) if ((d = spheres[i].intersect(r)) && d<t) { t = d; id = i; }
    return t<inf;
}
Vector3 radiance(const Ray &r_, int depth_, unsigned short *Xi) {
    double t;                               // distance to intersection
    int id = 0;                               // id of intersected object
    Ray r = r_;
    int depth = depth_;
    Vector3 cl(0, 0, 0);   // accumulated color
    Vector3 cf(1, 1, 1);  // accumulated reflectance
    while (1) {
        if (!intersect(r, t, id)) return cl; // if miss, return black
        const Sphere &obj = spheres[id];        // the hit object
        Vector3 x = r.o + r.d*t, n = (x - obj.p).norm(), nl = n.Dot(r.d)<0 ? n : n*-1, f = obj.f;
        double p = f.x>f.y && f.x>f.z ? f.x : f.y>f.z ? f.y : f.z; // max refl
        cl = cl + cf.mult(obj.e);
        if (++depth>5) if (erand48(Xi)<p) f = f*(1 / p); else return cl; //R.R.
        cf = cf.mult(f);
        if (obj.reflection_t == DIFFUSE) {                  // Ideal DIFFUSE reflection
            double r1 = 2 * M_PI*erand48(Xi), r2 = erand48(Xi), r2s = sqrt(r2);
            Vector3 w = nl, u = ((fabs(w.x)>.1 ? Vector3(0, 1) : Vector3(1)) % w).norm(), v = w%u;
            Vector3 d = (u*cos(r1)*r2s + v*sin(r1)*r2s + w*sqrt(1 - r2)).norm();
            r = Ray(x, d);
            continue;
        }
        else if (obj.reflection_t == SPECULAR) {
            r = Ray(x, r.d - n * 2 * n.Dot(r.d));
            continue;
        }
        Ray reflRay(x, r.d - n * 2 * n.Dot(r.d));
        bool into = n.Dot(nl)>0;
        double nc = 1, nt = 1.5, nnt = into ? nc / nt : nt / nc, ddn = r.d.Dot(nl), cos2t;
        if ((cos2t = 1 - nnt*nnt*(1 - ddn*ddn))<0) {
            r = reflRay;
            continue;
        }
        Vector3 tdir = (r.d*nnt - n*((into ? 1 : -1)*(ddn*nnt + sqrt(cos2t)))).norm();
        double a = nt - nc, b = nt + nc, R0 = a*a / (b*b), c = 1 - (into ? -ddn : tdir.Dot(n));
        double Re = R0 + (1 - R0)*c*c*c*c*c, Tr = 1 - Re, P = .25 + .5*Re, RP = Re / P, TP = Tr / (1 - P);
        if (erand48(Xi)<P) {
            cf = cf*RP;
            r = reflRay;
        }
        else {
            cf = cf*TP;
            r = Ray(x, tdir);
        }
        continue;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int w = 512, h = 384, samps = argc == 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) / 4 : 1; // # samples
    Ray cam(Vector3(50, 52, 295.6), Vector3(0, -0.042612, -1).norm()); // cam pos, dir
    Vector3 cx = Vector3(w*.5135 / h), cy = (cx%cam.d).norm()*.5135, r, *c = new Vector3[w*h];
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) private(r)       // OpenMP
    for (int y = 0; y<h; y++) {                       // Loop over image rows
        fprintf(stderr, "\rRendering (%d spp) %5.2f%%", samps * 4, 100.*y / (h - 1));
        for (unsigned short x = 0, Xi[3] = { 0,0,y*y*y }; x<w; x++)   // Loop cols
            for (int sy = 0, i = (h - y - 1)*w + x; sy<2; sy++)     // 2x2 subpixel rows
                for (int sx = 0; sx<2; sx++, r = Vector3()) {        // 2x2 subpixel cols
                    for (int s = 0; s<samps; s++) {
                        double r1 = 2 * erand48(Xi), dx = r1<1 ? sqrt(r1) - 1 : 1 - sqrt(2 - r1);
                        double r2 = 2 * erand48(Xi), dy = r2<1 ? sqrt(r2) - 1 : 1 - sqrt(2 - r2);
                        Vector3 d = cx*(((sx + .5 + dx) / 2 + x) / w - .5) +
                            cy*(((sy + .5 + dy) / 2 + y) / h - .5) + cam.d;
                        r = r + radiance(Ray(cam.o + d * 140, d.norm()), 0, Xi)*(1. / samps);
                    } // Camera rays are pushed ^^^^^ forward to start in interior
                    c[i] = c[i] + Vector3(clamp(r.x), clamp(r.y), clamp(r.z))*.25;
                }
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, "image.ppm", "w");         // Write image to PPM file.
    fprintf(fp, "P3\n%d %d\n%d\n", w, h, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i<w*h; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "%d %d %d ", toInt(c[i].x), toInt(c[i].y), toInt(c[i].z));
}
```

**First** `Ray` **structure**:

```
struct Ray { Vector3 o, d; Ray(const Vector3 &o_, const Vector3 &d_) : o(o_), d(d_) {} };
```

Results in:

[image]

**Second** `Ray` **structure**:

```
struct Ray { Vector3 o, d; Ray(const Vector3 &o_, const Vector3 &d_, double tmin=0.0, double tmax=0.0) : o(o_), d(d_) {} };
```

Results in:

[image]

The last image has a noticeable white top border which is not present in the first image.

**Edit**:

I used

```
size_t n = sizeof(spheres) / sizeof(Sphere);
```

Now I obtain the same images, but I also checked if the original `int(n)` could differ from 9 which is never the case.

Ok this is from the Debug build, which is different from the Release build.

Comment: What about the white border at the bottom? Both images seem to have it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight which white border at the bottom? I don't see one. It is just the StackOverlow background color (you can use DarkReader plugin for Chrome).

Comment: Have you tried changing optimization flags? I'm not familiar with MSVC, but gcc sometimes does weird things when optimization is turned on/off.

Comment: I select text and image on the page to see the white border on the top that you are talking about. It appears as a thin light-blue line. The bottom has the same thin blue line on both images when I select them on the page above.

Comment: Have you tried this without parallelizing the loops?

Comment: @Ohashi currently I don't use optimizations (Disabled flag)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight without OpenMP I got the same results

Comment: I just ran both versions of the ctor, with and without OpenMP, and saw no diff. (no white margins in both). Win10, MSVC 2015

Comment: @OfekShilon Since a fixed seed is used, both images correspond to the first one? (I converted them to png for StackOverflow)

Comment: I just compiled using GCC 4.9, no difference between the two images

Comment: @Matthias without OpenMP you get the same results - meaning both images are the same or the diff is the same?  Anyway it does look to me like a parallelization issue: the first few iterations of the parallelized loop (== the first few lines) behave differently. What happens if you change to schedule(static)?

Comment: @OfekShilon I removed the OpenMP and received the same two images as before but still different to each other. I also made a small edit (see question) which does not influence the program, but apparently now all images are the same and correct.

Comment: Since you don't use optimizations, those variables are doing something, they are zeroing stack space. If that changes program behavior, then you may have uninitialized variable bug. For example, there is a suspicious "t" in radiance function. It is being initialized in `intersect` as "inf = t = 1e20". But I don't know if this has a well defined behavior. If it is undefined (that some other experienced language lawyer can clarify) then compiler can do crazy things https://youtu.be/rNNnPrMHsAA?t=298

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a memory error, looking quickly at your code I'm sceptical of this line:

```
for (int i = int(n); i--;) if ((d = spheres[i].intersect(r)) && d<t)
```

<strike>I suspect accessing `sphere[i]` is out of bounds, perhaps you should try `sphere[i-1]`.</strike>  You could also try compiling your code with a compiler that adds extra code for debugging/sanitising/checking memory addresses.

Comment: I translated the program in Python, C# and C++ in a cleaner for loop. I always receive the image with the top white border. So the reference implementation could be wrong?

Comment: The type of `n` should be `std::size_t`. Generally you should never use floating point values for a size of an array (or any container).

Comment: `i` iterates from `8` to `0` (for condition is executed prior to for iteration) so `spheres` is never accessed out of bounds

Comment: @Ohashi `size_t` is `unsigned long` and array size is `9` so casting the `double` to an `int` suffice here (which does not mean I don't agree with your arguments)

Comment: @Matthias (replying to your 2nd comment) Quite a confusing way to write a `for` conditional, I'd venture to say. (to 3rd) Well yes, I think it's ok _for now_. But why you'd use a float for the first place? Sorry to be paranoia/offtopic, but I can't sleep well thinking that that `9` may become `8.999999991` or something after a refactoring, breaking the value of `n`.

Comment: @Ohashi I found the code online and didn't want to make more changes then necessary to illustrate the problem :) The code tries to be minimal with regard to the number of lines and so uses multiple local variable declarations for each statement, but these declarations must be of the same type.

Comment: @Ohashi I use the size_t and now it works, but the previous obtained size values were always correct. I begin to have the impression that the size of the file influences the output.

Comment: @Matthias Nice to hear your problem is resolved! I'm not exactly sure why it fixed the issue, however. :/ What I wanted to say is "It works now" is not a healthy way of thinking. Also the number of lines of _source code_ means little; any decent compiler (including MSVC) optimizes e.g. multiple declarations of variables so that your code runs fast. Writing code easier for _you_ to read will save much of your time.

Comment: @Ohashi Apparently it has something to do with the flags as you said above. No optimization (Debug) is correct, Optimization O2 (Release) is wrong. This is true for the above code as well as a cleaner and larger C++ version. I also have a C# and Python version and both are wrong. So only both C++ Debug builds are correct.

Comment: @Matthias Compiling your program with a setting that produces warnings _as many as possible_ and fixing them one by one may help you find the source of undefined behaviors (likely) or compiler bugs (unlikely); for example, my gcc-5.2.0 complains about `Xi` being narrow-converted and I found that `Xi` is effectively unused. Good luck.

Comment: @Ohashi originally erand48 is used, but I do not have that method in Windows so I use another random generator